# Get (sum of sales) MINUS (sum of refund) to calculate profit in SQL oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g

I am doing my database assignment, Airline Database.

So, I need to calculate profit for each flight.

Query 1 (Sum of `payment_amount` for each flight):

```
SELECT
         f.flight_id
       , SUM(r.payment_amount)
FROM
         flight_schedule f
       , reservation     r
WHERE
         r.flight_id = f.flight_id
GROUP BY
         f.flight_id
ORDER BY
         f.flight_id
;
```

Query 1 will return:

```
F0001              2000
F0002              2000
F0003              2000
F0004              2000
F0005              1000
```

Query 2 (Sum of `refund_amount` for each flight):

```
SELECT
         f.flight_id
       , SUM(e.refund_amount)
FROM
         refund          e
       , flight_schedule f
       , reservation     r
WHERE
         r.flight_id          = f.flight_id
         AND e.reservation_id = r.reservation_id
GROUP BY
         f.flight_id
ORDER BY
         f.flight_id
;
```

Query 2 will return:

```
F0001               50
F0002               50
F0003               50
F0004               50
F0005              100
```

So I want to get profit for each flight which is Query 1 that return `payment_amount` MINUS Query 2 that return `refund_amount`.

This is my expected output

```
F0001             1950
F0002             1950
F0003             1950
F0004             1950
F0005              900
```

I tried to used MINUS but I get error:

```
SP2-0042: unknown command "MINUS" - rest of line ignored.
```

I also tried to combine them:

```
SELECT
         f.flight_id
       , SUM(r.payment_amount) - SUM(e.refund_amount)
FROM
         refund          e
       , flight_schedule f
       , reservation     r
WHERE
         r.flight_id          = f.flight_id
         AND e.reservation_id = r.reservation_id
GROUP BY
         f.flight_id
ORDER BY
         f.flight_id
;
```

But I could not get the result I want

Here is my ERD:
[image: Entities involved]

Comment: MINUS is something completely different.  It would be useful to show you data sets too.  I am assuming there can be zero or more payment_amount and zero or more refund_amounts.  What did that last query return?

Comment: are you only getting the data for flights that have a refund?

Comment: yes, some flight dont have refund

Comment: The erd is useful.   It would also be useful to provide the input table data, so that troubleshooters can take it and test things off line.  take a look at sqlfiddle.com as a way to help with that.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I will provide that when I ask question next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **AND** In your join, requires that a refund exist.  the **(+)** says accept the data even if there is no refund match.

```
SELECT FLIGHT_ID, payX - payY
FROM
(
    SELECT
             f.flight_id
           , SUM(r.payment_amount) payX, SUM(e.refund_amount) payY
    FROM
             refund          e
           , flight_schedule f
           , reservation     r
    WHERE
             r.flight_id          = f.flight_id
             AND e.reservation_id(+) = r.reservation_id
    GROUP BY
             f.flight_id
)
ORDER BY
    flight_id
    ;
```

Comment: ah. there might be no refunds at all.

Comment: Ok.  Odds are your last query could be fixed with the (+) as well.   You need to read up on inner/outer/natural/full joins.  Prefer ANSI style joins.   I'm glad it worked for you.

Comment: This isn't an ideal way of writing this query.  _Always_ use explicit join notation and place the join logic into an `ON` clause.